# Error when multiple users access my web app at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

I'm using .Net 2008 and Oracle 10g as my database. The problem I'm getting is after deploying the application in IIS, when multiple users access the same page at a time i'm getting the error. Can't get the output.

Note: Both the users accessing the same page, same menu at a time.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you get an error message or no output? Is this a famous case of the "Nothing on the screen (except for an error message)"?

Comment: Was is ok with multiple users access in debug mode (Programming phase)?

Comment: s. its ok with debug mode, but while deploying the application in IIS and checking in 2 or more systems getting the erro!!

Comment: @user: **What** error, exactly?

Comment: Exception information: 
    Exception type: DataAccessException 
    Exception message: There was a problem creating the DataTable. 
 
CorpAct.DataAccess.ORADataFactory.CreateDataTable(DataRequest Request)
   at CRM.EHE.Database.DB_RRReport.getPortFolios(String strMonth, String strYear) in D:\Ranga\EHE Backup\CRM\CRM.EHE\CRM.EHE.Database\RRReport\DB_RRReport.cs:line 312
   at CRM.EHE.Business.BS_RRReport.getPortFolios(String strMon,

Comment: What's going on in DB_RRReport.cs, line 312?

Comment: This .Cs file contains the logic to fetch the data from oracle database by opening the connection, fetches the data and populates it to a grid view and closes the connection.

Comment: What is *literally* on line 312 (and around)? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be a standard thread-safety / synchronization bug, most likely due to some static resource such as a static connection. Obviously this is pure speculation without some more code, but it (=web-sites being highly threaded) is a surprisingly common oversight.

If it *is* a static resource, then... well, it probably shouldn't be static. Either per-request, or (specifically in the case of connections) scoped to the local code (and let the connection-pooling worry about re-use).

Answer (score 0):

You mean that nothing appears in the Browser?

Look in your program's logs. Any error messages?

Put some trace statements into your code so that you can figure out where it's going.

So the error is saying there's a failure to create a table. Would you expect to create a table for each user? Have a look at the code around the table creation. Consider what the correct behaviour should be when two copies of that code run at the same time.

Again add trace into the code at these points so you can see what happening. Often it's easier to see this than to debug because when mutiple threads are running the debugger gets in the way of reality.,

Comment: no i'm getting some exception and i'm using the error log too. when i check the event log its showing some error message. but can't get wat the error is....

Comment: You should tell us what the error messages and exceptions are

Comment: Exception information: Exception type: DataAccessException Exception message: There was a problem creating the DataTable. CorpAct.DataAccess.ORADataFactory.CreateDataTable(DataRequest Request) at CRM.EHE.Database.DB_RRReport.getPortFolios(String strMonth, String strYear) in D:\Ranga\EHE Backup\CRM\CRM.EHE\CRM.EHE.Database\RRReport\DB_RRReport.cs:line 312 at CRM.EHE.Business.BS_RRReport.getPortFolios(String strMon

Answer (score 0):

Does it "Work on your machine"? ;)

If not, try to deploy a version locally and attach the debugger to iis. Point two browsers at the site. Whenever your browsers are/seem stuck, open the debugger's threads window and see where the threads are blocked/blocking. You can also ask the debugger to stop on exception throwing

Comment: yes it works fine in my local machine. the problem is while deploying the application in IIS and accessing with two or three browsers getting the error!!!. How to attach the debugger to IIS???